# Sending and recieving response in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am sending an array from content.js to background.js in my chrome extension with success. Now, I want to send an array from background.js to content.js. I have tried a number of ways to do so, with sendMessage() even with (chrome.tabs.query) and also port.postMessage, but all of them fail with message: popup.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Below is the stucture of both content.js and background.js:
Contet.js:

```
function clickPlanet() {

const myDataArray  = [];

//myDataArray processed and prepared. 

  // Send a message to background.js and handle the response using a callback
  // This sendMessage is working flawlessly. 
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ myDataArray });
    
  // I have also tried the following, but I get the same error. 
  // Send a message to background.js and handle the response using a callback
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ myDataArray }, function (response) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
      return;
    }



}


// The function is just something I want to do again. I could do it without function, 
// But I don't think it would make a difference.
clickPlanet();


// I am expecting to recieve message from background.js here. 
// I don't get the message.indexArray at all, getting the same error. 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.indexArray) {
    const indexArray = message.indexArray;
    // Handle the received indexArray as needed in content.js
    console.log("Received indexArray in content.js:", indexArray);
  }

else {
    console.log("no index : ", message);
}
});
```

Background.js:

```
// This button is outside the onMessage, just checking if the issue is in that. 
// Getting error: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
document.getElementById('send-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log("ready");

  // Sending the indexArray to content.js
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { greeting: "hello" }, function (response) {
      // Handle the response from content.js if needed
      console.log("Response from content.js:", response);
      // Response from content.js: undefined
    });
  });

  const port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "content-script" });
  port.postMessage({ greeting: "Hello from background!" });
});



// Listen for messages from content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {


// This button gets data from indexeddb and compares it to myDataArray from content.js
document.getElementById('checkk-button').addEventListener('click', function() {


    const data = message.myDataArray;
    let db;
    // Open the IndexedDB database
    const request = indexedDB.open("OurDatabase4", 1);

    // Event handler when the database is successfully opened
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    db = event.target.result; // Set db when the request is successful

   

      // Data was found

// This array will be sent to content.js
indexArray = [];


// Have tried to look for active tabs and send indexArray there

  // Send indexArray as a response to content.js
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { indexArray }, function (response) {
      // Handle the response from content.js if needed
      console.log("Response from content.js:", response);
    });
  });


// OR 

 sendResponse({ indexArray });

}

});
```

Comment: Can you please format your code for better readability?

Comment: You need to [re-inject content scripts explicitly](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension.

Comment: @VaibhavNigam Sorry about the unreadable code before, have formatted it now !!